# How do I uninstall a click package?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, click-packages

As a developer, how do I uninstall a click package for Ubuntu Touch / Ubuntu Phone?

Answer (score 2):

It requires two steps.

First, get the full name of the click package. On the device, as the phablet user:

`click list`

And find the full package name in the first column.

Second, on the device as the root user:

`click unregister --user=phablet <package name>`

Where  is the full package name obtained in step 1.

The above can be scripted and run from your developer workstation like so:

```
#! /bin/sh

MATCH=$1
[ -n "$MATCH" ] || exit 1

PACKAGE="$(adb shell sudo -u phablet -i click list |grep $MATCH |sed -e 's/\t.*//')"

echo "found $PACKAGE, proceed with removal ? (y/n)"
read yesno
[ "$yesno" != "y" ] && exit 0

adb shell click unregister --user=phablet $PACKAGE
```

Thanks to Oliver Grawert for the above script.